# how to define a rule of a pattern repeated by a fixed number of times using antlr pure lexer grammar

Tags: grammar, antlr4, lexer

I'm trying to define a pure lexer grammar in Antlr that recognizes 32-bit in hexadecimal notation.

for now I have:

```
lexer grammar Grammar;

WS : [ \r\t\n]+ -> skip;

fragment HexDigit : ([0-9]|[A-f]|[a-f]);
fragment HexDigitNoZero : ([1-9]|[A-f]|[a-f]);
fragment HexNumber : (HexDigitNoZero)(HexDigit)*;
fragment Eight : HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit;

Hex :'0x'Eight;
```

I'd like to know if theres any way to define a range 8 in a pure lexer grammar.
Like Flex does with 'a'{8}.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a predicate (same as action but has `?` at the end)

```
(HexDigitNoZero)(HexDigit)* {getText().lenght!= 8}? {do_something;};
```

Tecnhically this is pure lexer, but uses gramar actions

Comment: Thx for advice: I used Hex :{getText().length()== 8}? '0x'(HexDigitNoZero)(HexDigit)*; and it worked perfectly.

Comment: You're welcome. If you could accept the answer, that'd be geat. :)